# Intermittent "Access denied" error running iisreset in Windows Server 2016

Tags: windows, security, iis, windows-server-2016

I'm seeing some very strange behavior on some Windows Server 2016 EC2 instances. In rare cases, `iisreset` fails with the error message:

```
Attempting stop...
Restart attempt failed.
Access denied, you must be an administrator of the remote computer to use this
command. Either have your account added to the administrator local group of
the remote computer or to the domain administrator global group.
```

I've seen this from an Administrative shell and from Chef client runs executed by cloud-init. What's more, I've seen multiple cases where I get this error in the shell, immediately execute the command again, in the same shell, and the second time it succeeds without issue. With cloud-init, I can have multiple instances with the same exact configuration (same AMI, same runlist, same environment), one will get the error, one won't.

So far everything I have found has been for consistent issues, and every case seems to have been solved by running the shell as an administrator; this is definitively not my issue. One post suggested completely disabling UAC, but this is a non-starter in a production environment.

Does anyone know what might be causing this, what might solve it, or even a direction I can take for further investigation?

Comment: same pain here... :(   I'm on Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

Since the message stated 'remote computer', I thought maybe if I specify the local computer name it would work, and it did.  Try `iisreset computername`.